# How to fix error Invalid environment variables with NextJS14 and Jest?

Tags: next.js, jestjs

I am using @t3-oss/env-nextjs to manage environment variables in my NextJS project but, when i try run Jest i get the error below:

```
 FAIL  tests/hello.spec.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Invalid environment variables

      2 | import { z } from 'zod'
      3 |
    > 4 | export const env = createEnv({
        |                             ^
      5 |   server: {
      6 |     APP_URL: z.string().url(),
      7 |   },
```

Seems like that line 4  is the problem but why? This Env was working normally, this error only happens when i run Jest, here is my env.ts:

```
import { createEnv } from '@t3-oss/env-nextjs'
import { z } from 'zod'

export const env = createEnv({
  server: {
    APP_URL: z.string().url(),
  },

  client: {
    NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL: z.string().url(),
  },

  runtimeEnv: {
    APP_URL: process.env.APP_URL,
    NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL,
  },
})
```

Here is my jest.setup.js:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { loadEnvConfig } from '@next/env'

loadEnvConfig(process.cwd())
```

Here is my jest.config.mjs:

```
import nextJest from 'next/jest.js'

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: './',
})

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const config = {
  // Add more setup options before each test is run
  // setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/.env.test'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
}

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
export default createJestConfig(config)
```

Here is my next.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
  eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
  typescript: {
    ignoreBuildErrors: true,
  },
  images: {
    domains: ['github.com'],
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Here is the package.json, i am not using Babel, i chose SWC insteed:

```
{
  "name": "devstoreplus",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "test": "jest --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@t3-oss/env-nextjs": "^0.7.1",
    "lucide-react": "^0.292.0",
    "next": "14.0.1",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.0.0",
    "zod": "^3.22.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rocketseat/eslint-config": "^2.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.1",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.8",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.62.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "cypress": "^13.5.1",
    "eslint": "^8.7.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.1",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
  
}
```

And finally here is the test code that i was trying to run, but is only a test to render a page home:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import Home from '../src/app/(store)/(home)/page'
import React from 'react'

describe('Home component', () => {
  test('renders highlighted product', async () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<Home />)
    expect(getByText('Moletom')).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

In the page home have this call for a fake api:

```
export default async function Home() {
  const products = await getFeaturedProducts()
  console.log(products)
  const [highlightedProduct, ...otherProducts] = await getFeaturedProducts()
```

my .env.local is in the root folder:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL = "https://api-devstore.vercel.app"
APP_URL = "http://localhost:3000"
```

the api:

```
import { env } from '@/env'

export function api(path: string, init?: RequestInit) {
  const baseUrl = env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL
  const apiPrefix = '/api'
  const url = new URL(apiPrefix.concat(path), baseUrl)

  return fetch(url, init)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

add dotenv to fix

```
import { createEnv } from '@t3-oss/env-nextjs'
import { config } from 'dotenv'
import { z } from 'zod'

config()

export const env = createEnv({})
```